# Retreival of data using RecyclerView in firebase

Tags: arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-recyclerview

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4xnx.png)

```
Adapter class:
```

This Is the Adapter class for my project.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> mProduct;

    public ProductAdapter(Context con, ArrayList<Product> list) {
        this.context = con;
        this.mProduct = list;
    }
    @Override
    public ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Product contact = mProduct.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(mProduct.get(position).getName());
        holder.pass.setText(mProduct.get(position).getPass());
        holder.ward.setText(mProduct.get(position).getWard());

    }
```

This is my **ValueEvent Listener**:

```
ValueEvent Listener:


        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();



        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Product item = snapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                    mProductList.add(item);
                }
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });









  Description:



Objective of this coding: Real time viewing of added members based on the Region & sub-region chosen under a state.

Attached image has the key of each member, their attributes added.

Based on this, the expectation is to list the members, however, the code does not return any error, except blank screen.
```

I try to Retreival all the "User" details in Recyclerview but the Blank Screen shows without any error.

```
I trying for past days. Please help me.
```

Objective of this coding: Real time viewing of added members based on the Region & sub-region chosen under a state.

```
Attached image has the key of each member, their attributes added.

Based on this, the expectation is to list the members, however, the code does not return any error, except blank screen.
```

I try to Retreival all the "User" details in Recyclerview but the Blank Screen shows without any error.

```
I trying for past 4 days. Please help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

now I solve this problem friends.
My mistakes is in "layout xml file",In linear layout I mention "matchparent" for the height, so linear layout should occupy all the space in xml.
After I changed "matchparent" to "warpcontent" I retrive all the datas....

```
        Thanks Friends....
```